# Marker from Firestore map data type

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, geofirestore

in Firestore I have a map data type called `latlng` that has latitude and longitude of a position. I would like to use this info in Android for the position of a marker. I have instinctively thought to use this code but it is wrong because it expects `(double, double)` instead of `(Object)`.

```
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(document.get("latlng")))
```

**EDIT**

Consider that the Firebase field is a **Map** data type because it is automatically imported in this way from Google Place API.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your error log

Comment: @Zachary done :) the error is that it expects `(double, double)` instead of `(Object)`.

Comment: Awesome.  Happy coding!

Comment: Lol. @Zachary, OP didn't say he has solved his problem.

Comment: yes sorry! my "done" was shifty. I meant that I have detailed the error.

Comment: Haha  @Taslim,  finding the exact error is the problem,  once you found it,  solution just comes on the way brother :)

Comment: Anyways,  @stefano,  follow Derek's answer,  you will be done :)

Comment: I put up a new answer @Stefano, check it out.

Comment: Aside from the answers below, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-display-locations-from-firestore-on-google-maps-using-jetpack-compose-9490c92c34da) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreGoogleMapsJetpackCompose).

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it would definitely work for you.

```
db.collection("latlng")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            HashMap hashmap = (HashMap) document.getData();
                            GeoPoint geopoint = new GeoPoint(hashmap.get("latitude"), hashmap.get("longitude"));
                            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(geopoint.getLatitude(), geopoint.getLongitude()));
                        }
                    } else {
                        // handle your errors here
                    }
                }
            });
```

Essentially, the codebase above queries the Firestore at the *latlng* node and gets all the geopoints at that location. It then proceeds to display a marker at each of the coordinates. I really hope this helps.

### ADDENDUM

There is a simpler way to store and retrieve location values form FirebaseDatabase. You can easily save and retrieve by using [GeoFire](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/08/geofire-goes-mobile.html). Read [the ReadMe of the official repository](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-android) to get a better grasp.

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Comment: Have you checked the rules in your Firestore? There is a high probability that this is the problem because I have reused this code snippet multiple times and it works for me all the time. Just check the error you are getting.

Comment: I am getting this error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.firestore.GeoPoint` Consider that the Firebase field is a map data type because it is created automatically in this way each time I add a new document with Google Place API

Comment: Lol, I can see exactly what the problem is now. I shall update this answer.

Comment: @TaslimOseni did u update your answer? I seem to get "GeoPoint(double, double) in GeoPoint cannot be applied to (java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)"

Comment: @badaboomskey, I edited the answer and this approach works fine here. You can try storing the lat and lng values in primitive double variables and then creating your GeoPoint off of them. That should work.

Comment: @TaslimOseni YOU are my hero! I shall name all my children Taslim. Joke aside, this worked and have been using too many hours being stuck on such a simple fix.

Comment: I'm really glad I was able to help. Thanks. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you see the documentation here: [**LatLng**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng)

The only public constructor available is **`LatLng(double latitude, double longitude)`**

**Edit:**

Create a new class to parse the reference.

```
public class MyLatLng {
    public Double latitude;
    public Double longitude;
 public MyLatLng(Double latitude, Double longitude) {
   this.latitude = latitude;
   this.longitude = longitude;
 }     
}
```

create a new Variable in your reference class to parse the `LatLng`

```
public MyLatLng latlng;
```

Now

```
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(document.latitude, document.longitude));
```

Comment: thanks. I tried but I get this error message `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng`

Comment: @Stefano I have updated the answer. Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: thanks. Consider that I am not using Firebase Storage but Firebase Database. I get the error in `.get("Latitude")` because of `Cannot resolve method`

Comment: @Stefano I have updated the answer. If doesn't work, let me know whats the return variable type of your method `document.get("latlng")`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.GeoPoint;
```

And put the values on a type

```
GeoPoint geopoint;
```

And then retrieve lat and long from there.